# Searching for multiple criteria in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Am a little new to excel and puzzled as to how to solve this problem. I have two excel sheets.

Sheet 1 looks like (large data set):

```
HIC    GSN     ND11
H1C    00214   0212107
C4I    07287   0214380
L1A    07731   0214501
```

Sheet 2 looks like:

```
Condition    HIC1   HIC1    HIC1    GSN      GSN     GSN
 AMA         B60     B61    B62     02934   02935
 ALD         H1A     H1C            04821   03473
 HEC         W0A     W0B
```

For example, in Table 1, if the HIC or GSN on row 1 (H1C or 00214) is present anywhere in table 2, it fetches the ND11 number from table 1 corresponding to the match. I tried using a VLOOKUP, but am failing at how to go about approaching the problem.

The VLOOKUP I tried was,

```
=VLOOKUP(OR(Table1'H1C', Table1'00214),Table2A2:G2,Table1'ND11',0)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't have Excel handy to check this and give you an exact answer, but you probably need to rearrange your Sheet2 so that all possible H1C values are in one column and the GSN values in another. Then you can use the MATCH function to see whether a value exists in the appropriate column in Sheet2.

Comment: The OR function would have to be outside the MATCH function, not within as in your VLOOKUP example - that's not how OR works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

OK, I re-read the question and I think I misunderstood; you want to match *`HIC` **or** `GSN`*.  In that case, I had to use some helper columns because I don't know of an way to arithmetically `OR` arrays.  So, I came up with this ...

[image: iferror with match screenshot]

... where `I7`, `J7`, and `K7` formulas are (respectively):

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(B7,$A$2:$A$4,0),IFERROR(MATCH(C7,$A$2:$A$4,0),IFERROR(MATCH(D7,$A$2:$A$4,0),NA())))
=IFERROR(MATCH(E7,$B$2:$B$4,0),IFERROR(MATCH(F7,$B$2:$B$4,0),IFERROR(MATCH(G7,$B$2:$B$4,0),NA())))
=INDEX($C$2:$C$4,IFERROR(I7,IFERROR(J7,NA())))
```

You could replace the last `IFERROR(J7,NA())` with just `J7`, but the Excel error handling will whine.

---

**ORIGINAL:**

If I understood your problem correctly (*which I doubt*), you want to get the `ND11` value from `Sheet1` for the matching `HIC` and `GSN` values.  For single matching, the `INDEX`/`MATCH` combo works well.  However, for multiple criteria, the `SUMPRODUCT` works better.  In the following screenshot ...

[image: sumproduct screenshot]

... I used the following formula to get the value of `ND11` in the first table only where the value from column C matches the `HIC` and column F matches the `GSN` ...

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--($A$2:$A$4=C10)*--($B$2:$B$4=F10))*$C$2:$C$4)
```

Now, I'm not sure why you have three HIC's and three GSN's, so **you'll have to elaborate on your question if this isn't the expected result**.

Comment: @reasara thanks. Am wondering if the opposite is possible as well? As in can we search all elements in table 2 and match them to table 1 (HIC1 and GSN) and return the associated ND11? There might be multiple matches for a single Condition in table 1 when being checked against table 2.

Comment: Sure. Same thing, just flip the single and array cell references. But if there could be multiple results, you'll have to use multiple cells (columns).

Comment: Thanks! SO can I make a column in Sheet1 right next to ND11 and match the items on Sheet2? Ideally, it would be nice if I could just match the ND11's on sheet 1 instead of Sheet 2. Sorry If I seem confused a bit.

Comment: Does seem very confusing.  You want to look for the HIC and GSN from Sheet1 in Sheet2?  Honestly, the best way to ask your question (_for future questions_) is to supply an example of your data and an example of your **expected result**.  If I understand your comment correctly, try this **array formula** in `D1` of my solution `=INDEX($A$8:$A$10,MATCH(1,--($B$8:$B$10=A2)+--($C$8:$C$10=A2)+--($D$8:$D$10=A2),0))`.

Comment: Thanks you. I managed to figure out a solution based on your updated answer. Thanks for the help.  :)

Comment: is it possible to get the corresponding value in col1(i.e the condition) if there is a match?

Comment: The term "match" is vague, but something like `=INDEX($A$8:$A$10,[match])` and replace [match] with the row of the "match" that you found.  You'll have to be more specific or post another question, and please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a **complete** question.

Comment: I apologize. What I was trying to ask was that in the updated version of your solution, if along with the NDC I could also get the 'Condition' (Sheet 2, Col1) as well.

Comment: Yes, index A, not C